# name : "ObjectUnsubscribedError" using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, subscription

I have this bug on my code

> ObjectUnsubscribedErrorImpl {message: 'object unsubscribed', name:
> 'ObjectUnsubscribedError', ngDebugContext: DebugContext_,
> ngErrorLogger: ƒ} message :  "object unsubscribed" name :
> "ObjectUnsubscribedError"

I have this code:

```
 clickSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  l_getClickButtonCancella(event: boolean) {
    if (event) {
      this.clickSubject.next(1);
    }
  }
```

Can you share with me any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Check your code where you are unsubscribing the subject anywhere ( Remove the unsubscribe on the subject to fix the error! ), that is the reason, please check the below stackblitz where I replicated your scenario!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  clickSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clickSubject.next(1);
    this.clickSubject.unsubscribe();
    this.clickSubject.next(1);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qyhtqg?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: I keep getting this error.